# Grouping form elements together

Tags: css, forms, grid

I'm trying to create two css container classes that can be used to:

- Vertically align form elements using `.group`.
- Horizontally align form elements using `.group.group--inline`.

Each for element will use the class `.group__item` to make sure there's 16px vertical and horizontal distance between the form elements. For example:

```
.group__item { margin-top: 16px; }
```

I however want to sure that the entire height and width of the `.group` can be used for the form elements and that there is no unwanted whitespace. Not having any margin around our components makes it easier to properly layout them.

[image]

To negate the margin on the `.group__item`'s I'm adding it as negative margin to the `.group` and `.group--inline`. For example:

```
.group { margin-top: -16px; }
```

I'm wondering if there are any negative side effects to giving the `.group` container a negative margin?

```js
function toggleGroupBorder() {
  var groups = document.querySelectorAll('.group');
  
  for (var i = 0, j = groups.length; i < j; i++) {
    groups[i].classList.toggle('group--show-border');
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 32px;
  padding: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #99f;
}

.group {
  margin-top: -16px;
}

.group.group--show-border {
  border: 1px solid #f99;
}

.group .group__item {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.group.group--inline {
  margin-left: -16px;
}

.group.group--inline .group__item {
  margin-left: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

input {
  height: 32px;
  padding: 0 8px;
}

button {
  height: 32px;
  padding: 0 24px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleGroupBorder();">Toggle Group Border</button>

<h2>Vertical field alignment using <code>.group</code></h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="group">
    <input class="group__item" type="text" />
    <input class="group__item" type="text" />
    <button class="group__item" >Default</button>      
  </div>
</div>

<h2>Horizontal field alignment using <code>.group.group-inline</code></h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="group group--inline">
    <input class="group__item" type="text" />
    <input class="group__item" type="text" />
    <button class="group__item" >Default</button>      
    <input class="group__item" type="text" />
    <input class="group__item" type="text" />
    <button class="group__item" >Default</button>      
    <input class="group__item" type="text" />
    <input class="group__item" type="text" />
    <input class="group__item" type="text" />
    <button class="group__item" >Default</button>          
  </div>
</div>
```

Or see this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/aOQXLK)

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly **what** it is that you are trying to achieve, but currently failing at? Do you want the parent `.group` to adapt its size to its content, or the other way around?

Comment: It currently exactly does what I want, it's just that I'm not sure if there are any side effects to using the negative margin on the .group that I should be aware of. This sounds easy, but for example bootstrap uses .btn + .btn inside its .btn-group

Comment: I confess I'm not sure what structure you will be using. Will you actually be grouping these elements or just putting them all in one container and using some sort of magic to make them into rows? If each `row` (in your second image) was a separate group that would make sense to me. Then we could work on something. Is the width of the `container` fixed or flexible.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to layout form elements, in either a vertical layout or a horizontal one where the form elements wrap if they don't fit their container anymore. A container class should be able to constrain the dimensions of the `.group`. I want to keep the form elements at 16px distance from eachother, and they should not be able to fill the entire `.group`.